# Update parent and child entities in same PUT and navigation link with olingo2

Tags: java, odata, olingo

I have two questions:
1- Is it possible to update a parent entity and its child by single PUT using Olingo2?

2- Is it possible to update a navigation link (many-to-one relationship) of an entity? (ex updating Product entity Product.categoryId = 1 --> Product.categoryId = 2)

I read the documentation and that it is possible with odata4 and olingo4 but I am not sure that it is possible natively with olingo2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1° it is not mentioned into odata specifications, the only way is to perform a $batch

2°  it is possible like this:

PUT http://host:port/odata/Entities(parentID)

{
    "RelationshipDetails":
    {
        "__metadata": {
            "uri": "http://host:port/odata/Relationships(newRelationshipID)"
        }
    }
}